# Queued Waiting for run to start with conditional parallel stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Here is a sample pipeline to reproduce. Using Jenkins 2.414.1 w/ Blue Ocean 1.27.6.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_DEPLOY_LG', defaultValue: true, description: 'Deploy to LG')
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_DEPLOY_SM', defaultValue: true, description: 'Deploy to SM')
    }

    stages {
        stage ("Deploy") {
            parallel {
                stage('SM') {
                    when { expression { params.IS_DEPLOY_SM } }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            echo 'Running SM'
                            sleep 15
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('LG') {
                    when { expression { params.IS_DEPLOY_LG } }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            echo 'Running LG'
                            sleep 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When both boolean params are true (checked) the parallel pipeline stages run as expected while the pipeline runs.

[image]

If only one parameter is true, Blue Ocean shows Queued Waiting for run to start for the duration of the pipeline.

This seems like it could be a bug but not sure, is there anything wrong with the pipeline code?

[image]

Only after the pipeline finishes does it show the completed stage.

[image]

Comment: Blue Ocean does have issues here and there, so this might be a bug from there end. If you check the console logs (non-blue ocean) and see the pipeline running as intended, you can be sure of it.

Comment: This is a bug in either BlueOcean or Jenkins core, as I can see this issue even outside of BlueOcean.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to create a bug ticket about this on Jenkins Jira but looks like there's one already - https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-48879. In the comments, a suggested workaround is to add a dummy stage and that appears to help e.g. -

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_DEPLOY_LG', defaultValue: true, description: 'Deploy to LG')
        booleanParam(name: 'IS_DEPLOY_SM', defaultValue: true, description: 'Deploy to SM')
    }

    stages {
        stage ("Deploy") {
            parallel {
                stage('SM') {
                    when { expression { params.IS_DEPLOY_SM } }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            echo 'Running SM'
                            sleep 15
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('LG') {
                    when { expression { params.IS_DEPLOY_LG } }
                    steps {
                        script {
                            echo 'Running LG'
                            sleep 15
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('(Workaround)') {
                    steps {
                        sleep 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```